# Why did Van Helsing not follow through?

Tags: plot-explanation, dracula-tv

In Episode 6 of *Dracula*, after being effectively fired by Van Helsing Mina reveals she found a vial of what we assume is Dracula's blood given her description of what she observed it doing.

As Mina is telling Van Helsing her story of how her mother died, we see Van Helsing grab the metal hammer he used when he killed The Order's Seer Twins and looks to kill her but at the last moment doesn't do it.

But why did Van Helsing not follow through? It's not like that Mina's mother was killed by the Order of the Dragon like his family and the fact he was going to do it meant that she posed as a threat to their operations against the Order.